# How to use Sim7020_mini NB-IOT module

Tags: serial, communication

> I bough Sim7020_mini module. I put IOT Sim card, and plug-in antenna,
> connect Rx,Tx into USB-TTL, then put supply into VIN (5 volt), LED
> power was lid on. Arduino Serial Monitor set into 115200, but no
> character appear, also I enter AT, no answer. I already making sure my
> wiring. Measuring STATUS pin 42 showing 1.8 volt, means not active.
>
> Schematic look like wrong, according to sim7020 Hardware design v1.02,
> to put SIM7020 to On we should give LOW pulse 1 second into PWRKEY.
> But STATUS pin still 1.8 volt.
>
> May anyone has successful using this such module? Any clue?

[First question about using SIM7020_mini Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72073576)

Thank you @hcheung for clue about 1.8 volt.

The SIM7020_mini module already equipped with logic level shifter between 1.8v and 3.3v.

I know SIM 7020C already Up, pin `STATUS` (42) is HIGH, pin `NETLIGHT` (41) blinking.

Here is my schematic, I just want to enter AT Command first. But on my Serial Monitor (Arduino) doesn't show any character received.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCADEM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When I type 'AT' it's echoed back to screen Serial Monitor. When I reverse Tx/Rx between SIM7020_mini module and USB-TTL, no character echoed. When I restart SIM7020_mini module, there is no character received by Serial Monitor.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of all the header pins naming? or a link to where you purchase the module?

Comment: Pin Header 1: `VIN`, `GND`, `PCE`, `GIO1`, `RESET`, `TXD`, `RXD`
Pin Header 2: `VBAT`, `GND`, `DTR`, `RI`, `RGIO0`, `EINT`, `DET`

[SIM7020_mini module](https://id.aliexpress.com/item/1005003546764346.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.260e373256CcxA&algo_pvid=7301788d-8ddb-4614-a9e7-6fa9140dd52d&algo_exp_id=7301788d-8ddb-4614-a9e7-6fa9140dd52d-2&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000026239378543%22%7D&pdp_npi=1%40dis%7CIDR%7C%7C174759.0%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%400b0a555f16514982457405614e7aeb%7C12000026239378543%7Csea)

Comment: `VBAT`: Lithium battery input positive 3.7-4. 2V
`GND`: Lithium battery input negative
`DTR`: Control module sleep and wake up
`RI`: Ringing indicator
`RTC_GPI0O`: PSM mode indication, before and after entering PSM mode, the pin changes from high to low
`RTC_EINT`: wake up from PSM mode, when this pin changes from high to low, exit PSM mode
`SIM DET`: SIM card insertion detect
`VIN`: Power input positive 5V (1A)
`GND`: negative power
`PCE`: Power enable control
`GPI01`: General purpose input/output port
`RESET`: reset control
`TXD`: Serial transmission
`RXD`: serial receiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault, AT command on Serial Monitor (Arduino IDE) should be ending with `Carriage Return`, while my Serial Monitor using `New Line`

Thank you for responses.